# Difference Source and Datacontext in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

DataContext and Source seem to be very similar to me.

- What are the advantages and disadvantages?
- When to use which one?

With Source:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Source={StaticResource Person}}" />
```

Or the solution with DataContext:

```
public partial class DataContextSample : Window
    {
      public string Name {get; set;}
        public DataContextSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

Comment: The certainly most common way of setting a binding's source object is to set a DataContext. It is a dependency property with value inheritance, i.e. all children of the element where it is set will get the same DataContext. It is also automatically set by the framework in certain binding scenarios, e.g. on the item container of an ItemsControls, to the associated item of the ItemsSource collection.

Comment: Besides that, there is not only DataContext and Source, but also RelativeSource and ElementName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binding with out a specified Source binds to the DataContext property of the element.

The DataContext is a special property which, if not set, is redirected to the element's parent's DataContext. This prevents duplicate xaml (always setting the Source in every binding) and makes all bindings relative so it is easier to change the UI without having to adjust all Sources in the bindings.